# Using a plugin's update site when using yoxos instead of what is found in the marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, yoxos

I went after eclipse-glance in the Eclispe Marketplace using yoxos, but that of no avail. My last resort seems to be to use glance's update site (http://eclipse-glance.googlecode.com/svn/site/).

Is there any way to do that through yoxos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoxos hasn't supported this because we can't ensure that all the dependencies will be met and that no conflicts will occur (we pre-validate all the plugins in the Yoxos distribution to ensure that they will install).

However, I've been working on an enhancement to the Yoxos Launcher that will allow you to re-enable the standard p2 install manager, and Yoxos will do a best effort to insure these plugins are installed.  This will be ready within the Month (March 2012).